# Failed to execute 'insertBefore' exit-intent-popup beeker.io

Tags: popup, exit-intent

On one of my pages I get a "Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node':".  I've checked the code headers, etc and can't find why.  The code I'm using is

https://github.com/beeker1121/exit-intent-popup

Answer (score 0):

After going through the code.  I found that the code is looking for "" tag in the .  If you put a blank one in there the code will work.  hope this helps someone.